# What is this data format?

Tags: json, dataformat

I'm working with json data from an external source, and for some reason they've encoded extra data in one of the values, instead of putting it in separate fields. Is this following some kind of standard? I've never seen it and I need to parse it somehow. The json looks like this:

```
{
    "description": "Description text here. \n #1621R5N9-{:organization/name \"Redacted Co.\", :organization/logo \"http://www.example.com/logo_redacted.png\", :organization/id 23, :organization/website \"http://example.com\", :organization/office []}-16722"
}
```

Comment: According to JSON Lint it's.. a normal JSON value pair. "description" points to that value.  I get the feeling that this is a custom data format, and the inner {} contains value pairs that you have to parse. A clue is that every pointer starts with colon (:)

Comment: Sort of looks like an Erlang map, or something related to Elixir atoms. Where is the data coming from? What sort of tech stack is surrounding it? what's your best guess?

Comment: I'm guessing ruby/elixir string interpolation of some kind.

Comment: @Malky.Kid It is normal JSON, but it has this other data in it.

Comment: @jmunsch I know nothing about their tech stack, the data is posted to our system on a schedule and other than that there is no interaction between us.